# How can I plot the average of a column based off of the values in another column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a list of campaign donations and I want to create a plot with the average 'contribution_receipt_amount' for each candidate.

```
indv.columns

#produces this code
#Index(['candidate_name', 'committee_name', 'contribution_receipt_amount',
       'contribution_receipt_date', 'contributor_first_name',
       'contributor_middle_name', 'contributor_last_name',
       'contributor_suffix', 'contributor_street_1', 'contributor_street_2',
       'contributor_city', 'contributor_state', 'contributor_zip',
       'contributor_employer', 'contributor_occupation',
       'contributor_aggregate_ytd', 'report_year', 'report_type',
       'contributor_name', 'recipient_committee_type',
       'recipient_committee_org_type', 'election_type',
       'fec_election_type_desc', 'fec_election_year', 'filing_form', 'sub_id',
       'pdf_url', 'line_number_label'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Can you post a data sample and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate `mean` to `Series` and then use [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
indv.groupby('candidate_name')['contribution_receipt_amount'].mean().plot()
```